# Convertir(MskDteDu, "E") To VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vb6, vb.net-2010, vb6-migration

I want to migrate the function `Convertir(MskDateDu,"E")` of VB6 to VB.NET.
Can someone please explain to me what the meaning of this instruction: Convertir(MskDate,"E") and how to code it in VB.NET
MskDate is mask date in this format `##/##/####`

Thank you

Comment: any suggestions please

Comment: Convertir(MskDateDu,"E") is calling the method Convertir, and passing to it the paramters, MskDateDu, and "E".

Comment: @jac thank you, but im looking for the meaning why "E" what for ? and how to code it in VB.NET ?

Comment: You're don't understand. From what you have posted, that you're calling a method is all we can know. Convertir is a method within the code. You didn't post the method code so we know nothing about it. MskDateDu is a parameter to the method. There is nothing in your post that defines what it is. "E" is a parameter to the method, the method code is not shown so there is no way to tell how it is used. First, it is unlikely that anyone will simply convert your code for you. Second, you do not have enough information in your post to explain what is being done.

Comment: I see it is so clear that this function has as first argument a date in this Format ##/##/#### and the second a String. that's clear. and if someone is expert in VB6 and .NET can understand it. About me, I got project in VB6 and i should understand th source code which is not mine and translate it into VB.NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convertir is NOT an internal function of VB6 - it´s a function created by someone.

MskDate also may be related to a NAME OF A MASKED-EDIT control. You can set DATE as a mask of this kind of control.

The "E" parameter is also a internal flag of the custom function above - it´s not a default parameter of the MaskedEdit control of VB6.

See here a sample of date mask in the .NET control:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask(v=vs.110).aspx